# Haskell + SDL, not understanding function/state usage

Tags: haskell, monads, haskell-sdl

**note** first, I am not sure how to title this question as I don't know exactly what the problem is.

I've been playing around with Haskell+SDL a bit and am stuck.
My GitHub repo is here: https://github.com/kennycason/haskell_boxxle/

on Line 209 there is a line of code:

`quit <- whileEvents $ modifyPlayerPos . handleKeyboard`

It works to move just the player, but I really want to be able to modify the other contents stored in`GameData` as well, i.e. data stored in `Room` (namely `boxes = [Coord]`)

I start out the loop via:

```
runLoop :: GameConfig -> GameData -> IO ()
runLoop = evalStateT . runReaderT loop


main = withInit [InitEverything] $ do -- withInit calls quit for us.
    (gConf, gData) <- newGame 1
    runLoop gConf gData
```

But after I get in loop I really don't know how to gain access to `gData` again, or even if I did, how to write the `modify` functions as I did for the other values inside GameData (`modifyPlayerPos`, etc).

I copied and modified `handleKeyboard` into `handleKeyboard2` to demonstrate the types I am wanting to pass to handleKeyboard.

I am a still new to Monads and Haskell, so I appreciate any advice. Let me know if my question is not clear enough. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have a specific answer for you, since I'm not familiar with the SDL library, but you should read up on Monad Transformers to get a better understanding of what is going on. Real World Haskell has a Chapter on that http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monad-transformers.html

Comment: @tauli Thanks, I've been reading about them for the last few hours. But I can't seem to find a way to access the `GameData` inside the loop function, despite calling it via.  `runLoop :: GameConfig -> GameData -> IO ()
runLoop = evalStateT . runReaderT loop`  I can only figure out how to pass single fields to the keyboard handler. I'll read through the chapters again :)

Answer (score 2):

After some talk on the forums (thanks donri) I was able to figure out how to properly write my get/put/modify state functions:

```
getGameData :: MonadState GameData m => m GameData
getGameData = get -- This line is what I couldn't figure out!

putGameData :: MonadState GameData m => GameData -> m ()
putGameData = put

modifyGameData :: MonadState GameData m => (GameData -> GameData) -> m ()
modifyGameData = modify
```

Comment: `putGameData = put` and `modifyGameData = modify `

Comment: Indeed :) I basically just copied pasted my other functions